# Accessing Dynamic Data from Drop down box in Shiny

Tags: rstudio, shinydashboard

I am creating a shiny dashboard wherein I need to dynamically update information based on an option in a drop down box.

My question is 1. can this be done, and if so: how?

I have created my drop down menu, which works fine, from there I want to same something along the lines of "if outlet xyz is picked, update charts with unique information"

Code thus far:

```
output$Box1 = renderUI(
selectInput("Outlets",
"Select an Outlet",
 c("Start Typing Outlet 
Name",as.character(unique(outlets$Outlets))),
"selectoutlet"))
```

once the outlet has been selected, I want the data in my R script to only update for that one outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As You havent supplied reproducible example, here is the code with `mtcars` dataset:

```
 library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui= fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId= "cyl", label= "cyl", 
                     choices= unique(mtcars$cyl), 
                     selected= sort(unique(mtcars$cyl))[1],
                     multiple=F)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server= function(input, output,session) {

  df_filtered <-reactive({
    data <- mtcars %>%  {if (is.null(input$cyl)) . else filter(., cyl %in% input$cyl)} # here is the reactive dataset which You can further use it in table or in the plot
    print(data)
    data
  }) 

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = df_filtered(), aes(x=cyl,y=mpg)) + geom_point(size=5) # as You can see i have used data = df_filtered()
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Have a look at the comments in the code to get some better idea how it works.